# ¿Como mandar un formulario por partes?

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy creando una página web, tengo 1 formulario dividido en 4 pestañas mi duda es como puedo mandar a la BD cada parte de los datos, pues es una sola tabla todo el formulario, me estan pidiendo poder guadar por ejemplo el formulario de la pestaña uno y despues poder contestar el 2 y asi sucesivamente, pero quiero saber como irlo mandando a la DB ya que un insert del 25% de los datos no funciona
Seria hacer un insert con los datos en blanco e ir haciendo update de cada parte del formulario?
MUCHAS GRACIAS

Comment: Creo que tú mismo has contestado a la pregunta. Si no puedes hacer un insert con únicamente los datos que te llegan desde el primer formulario, o bien modificas la base de datos para que los campos acepten null, o bien los insertas tú como cadenas vacías. También podrías establecer en esos campos valores predeterminados. Como sea, hay más de una opción para llegar a ese fin, y todas podrían ser válidas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes guardar los datos de cada formulario en una variable de sesión y cuando el usuario termine de llenar los datos, hacer un insert con todos los datos juntos. Algo asi

```
<?php

  session_start();

  $_SESSION['form1'] = array(
    'nombre' = $_GET['nombre'],
    'edad' = $_GET['edad']
  )
<?
```

Comment: Pero eso no funcionaría si el usuario se sale y vuelve a entrar o si? GRACIAS